# Achieving 2 million connections to Windows server

Tags: sockets, networking, windows-server-2008

In a question [How did WhatsApp achieve 2 million connections per server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090229/how-did-whatsapp-achieve-2-million-connections-per-server) it has been mentioned that two million concurrent connections have been achieved on FreeBSD server by "tweaking the kernel".

I am not much well versed with FreeBSD or *nix based OSes. I am working on Windows server development and like to know how can this (2 million connections) be achieved on Windows server? Is there any tweaking need to do on Windows? If yes, what is that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you install a custom socket stack that supports that many connections, it is probably unlikely that you can get that high with WinSock on Windows.  Thousands, certainly.  10/100's of thousands, maybe.  Millions, probably not.